# Is express default app.listen a good production server

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am currently using `app.listen(8080)` for express js developement. I am new to nodejs, I from python. I usually use [gunicorn](https://www.gunicorn.org) for server, and was wondering what a good production server like that for node would be. I could not find anything after a lot of googling. So, is the default `app.listen` good in production? Or even the `http` module in nodejs? I am deploying on heroku by the way. Any guidance appreciated.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The node HTTP server or app.listen [which is pretty much the same thing and just calls the Node HTTP server; app.listen() is for when using the Express framework] are perfectly fine to use if you only need a basic server. It depends on your application though. If you need more advanced features like load balancing of multiple Node.js servers, a web application firewall, HTTP/2, or SSL, then a common practice is to use Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of your Node.js deployment. See [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/) for more details on doing that.

But if you don't need anything fancy related to the HTTP side of your app, then using the built in HTTP server, directly or via Express with app.listen(), is just fine.